"@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises" for removing of async event handlers from DOM elements case
In below example, the async event listener is being removed from the HTMLElement. It has been treated as @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises by the TypeScript ESLint plugin:
let button: HTMLELement;

// ...

async function hideAndUnmountSnackbar(): Promise<void> {
  // ...
}

// ESLint: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)
button.removeEventListener("click", hideAndUnmountSnackbar);

I have checked the documentation for the  rule but have not found an example similar to mine. However, to disable this rule by eslint-disable-next-line comment, some justification is required.
Is there such justification, or I just doing something wrong?

The rule also check for void returns and do not allow Promise returning methods in those cases.
Event listeners return void, and we are returning a Promise<void>. That is the crux of the problem.
checksVoidReturn is the configuration.
The doc mentions how to switch it off:
{
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
    "error",
    {
      "checksVoidReturn": false
    }
  ]
}

The above rule might be too broad for some cases, and the most specific rule you can use to fix this is by not allowing the rule only for arguments:
{
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
    "error",
    {
      "checksVoidReturn": {
        "arguments": false
      }
    }
  ]
}

Playground

Note that this would have also worked: button.removeEventListener("click",() => { hideAndUnmountSnackbar() });.
